# Comment removal philosophy

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I really hate to ask this, because it's about a single comment flag, but can we get some clarification on what the moderators consider good vs bad comments?

I am asking because a flag I had on the following comment was declined:

> I'm sorry, why do you disapprove of this answer, downvoter?

I've had a few other declined comment flags, but when looking through them, they were all removed later. Unfortunately, that means I can't provide examples of what they were before someone either went back through and removed them or other community users flagged them as well.

(Edit, later on:)

Here's an example of an comment that had an "obsolete" flag on it declined:

> @Andy feel free to add that to the answer  – Firepower0701 Sep 14 at 18:11

It was flagged as obsolete because an edit negated the point it made.

---

The comment above is not constructive. Users can vote however they wish for whatever reason they wish. They also do not need to provide any other feedback. Granted, it'd be *nice* if they did, but asking for such feedback doesn't accomplish anything except add noise to a post.

My question, before I continue flagging and seeing either declined flags or declined and eventually removed, what do the moderators want *removed* from the site that we should be flagging?

Comment: I'll let the moderator that handled these respond to this specific case, but I agree with you that these should be deleted. Great discussion for the community to be having, thank you!

Comment: I had a dig, and identified one "obsolete" flag you had declined - I've edited it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was the one who declined the flag on that comment.

At the time, the comment appeared to ask a perfectly legitimate question, which it still does, but I see how it is definitely noise. I guess this was a single case where I confused general noise with something that could be helpful.

I'll remove the comment soon. As for what we want removed, the best blanket description is *anything that is flaggable* (excluding the custom reason unless you honestly have a decent one to give). This means general noise, spam, too chatty, rude/offensive, not constructive, or obsolete comments.

Comments should essentially be only used as a way to ask for more info, discuss current info, or provide notes that can help solve the author's problem.